# UFW rule and website

Tags: dns, firewall, ufw

I am running an ubuntu server with pihole DNS server and OpenVPN server on it. I am running it on the internet so I wanted to protect it with ufw.

So following is my configuration for the ufw. Everything works, VPN + DNS push via VPN. But I can't access the pihole website served on the port 80 as long as UFW is enabled.

I have same setup on other server, this is essentially a migration from there. It works over there but not on this server. What am I missing here?

BTW I can access pihole website via private IP address. 10.x.x.x

```
     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 3222/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0 (out)
[ 3] Anywhere on tun0           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 4] 1194                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 5] 53/udp                     ALLOW IN    <work ip>
[ 6] 53/udp                     ALLOW IN    <home ip>
[ 7] 80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    <home ip>
[ 8] 80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    <work ip>
[ 9] 3222/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[10] Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6) on tun0 (out)
[11] Anywhere (v6) on tun0      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[12] 1194                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect website with VPN, I think you can allow IP VPN to port 80 on server as:

```
ufw allow from [IP VPN]  to any port 80
```

After you can check telnet to server with port 80:

```
[root@test test]# netstat -tulpn |grep 80
```

On Server OPENVPN you can add line route in file config /etc/openvpn/[name].conf as:

```
push "route [IP Server Web] 255.255.255.0"
```

On Server you can check allow IP Forwarding and Edit `/etc/default/ufw` and set `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY` to `ACCEPT`:

```
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"
```

Comment: Thanks. I it no longer an issue. I reconfigured my firewall to allow traffic on tun0 and no longer have to make exceptions for the different IP addresses. Also DNS server was only listening on public interfaces, I also changed it to listen it on the tun0. So now I have VPN + DNS working with min rules.